# Probability of last cheese

Tags: probability, gambling

I hope that someone could help me with understanding the exercise.

In a cycle shaped house there are n chambers. In this house there is a mouse and each chamber has cheese except the room where the mouse starts. Every chamber has also two adjoining chambers, and each of those two chambers has the same probability to be visited.  I need to show that each cheese has the same chance of being eating by the mouse with the probability of 1/n.

I thought about myself to proof this I will first try it with 7 chambers.

As shown in this picture:

[image]]

To calculate the probability I thought about the following:

$$ c0 = 0 (no cheese) $$ 
$$ cn = 1 (lastCheese) $$ 
$$ c1 = {1\over2}(c0 + c2) $$ 
$$ c2 = {1\over2}(c1 + c3) $$ 
$$ c3 = {1\over2}(c2 + c4) $$ 
$$ c4 = {1\over2}(c3 + c5) $$ 
$$ c5 = {1\over2}(c4 + c6) $$ 
$$ c6 = {1\over2}(c0 + c5) $$

But I am not sure if this correct and I have no idea how I can proof for n chambers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean by the cheese "being eaten by the mouse". I'm guessing the mouse wanders around the house for a "long" time, and stops in one room to eat the cheese.

In this case, this would be a question from stochastic processes where you are attempting to find the stationary distribution, i.e. find $\pi$ such that $\pi=\pi P$, where $\pi$ is your stationary distribution vector (of length $n$) and $P$ is the transition matrix which is the zero matrix with $1/2$ on the off-diagonals (except for the first and last rows which are $(0,\frac{1}{2},0,0,...,0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2},0,0,...,0,\frac{1}{2},0)$ respectively), in which case you have a system of equations that is solved by $\pi=(\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n})$.

In particular:

$$ \begin{align} \pi_1 &=\frac{1}{2}(\pi_2+\pi_n)\\
\pi_k &=\frac{1}{2}(\pi_{k-1}+\pi_{k+1}) \quad k=2,...,n-1\\
\pi_n &=\frac{1}{2}(\pi_1+\pi_{n-1})\\
\end{align}$$

such that $\pi_1+...+\pi_n=1$ is solved by $\pi_m=\frac{1}{n}$ for $m=1,...,k$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I mean with “being eaten by the mouse” that in every chamber the mouse enters; he is going to eat the cheese and I need to show that every cheese has the same probability to be eaten as last. Is it possible that you could explain a bit more of why the first row also have 1/2 in the transition matrix?

Comment: Do you mean to say that, for your 7 chamber question, if the mouse follows the path, say 0-1-0-6-5-6-0-1-2-3-4-5-6 for example, then in this case cheese 4 is eaten last, and you're trying to show that the probability of this happening is 1/6? If this is the case, then the answer I have posted is a solution to a different question.


(But for the question I believe I answered, there are 1/2's in the first row of the transition matrix because from room 0, you can move to room (matrix column) 2 and room (matrix column) n with equal probability.)

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation skills. I think you solved the correct question, because in my question for example the mouse follows:  0-1-0-6-5-6-0-1-2-3-4, than 4 is the last cheese and i have to calculate that 4 has the probability of 1/n to be eaten.  All the rooms after 4(last cheese) doesn't matter in the question

Comment: So, then, do you mean $P(\text{the last cheese to be eaten is in room $k$}) = 1/6$ for all $k, 1 \leq k \leq 6$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to calculate.

Comment: In that case, the answer I have given does not solve the problem; for a start, for the answer to be $1/n$, the room chambers should be labeled $0,1,...,n$. Finding the stationary distribution might not be the best (or even correct) way to solve this problem.